# Bash continue [n] ignored in piped to while read loops. for loop behaves as expected

Tags: bash, shell

In a script I'm writing, I try to exit out of the second nested while loop, and the continue statement appears to be simply ignored, and I'm unsure of exactly why.

From the manual:

```
continue [n]:
    Resume  the  next  iteration of the enclosing for, while, until, or select loop.  If n is specified,
    resume at the nth enclosing loop.  n must be ≥ 1.  If n is greater  than  the  number  of  enclosing
    loops,  the last enclosing loop (the ``top-level'' loop) is resumed.  The return value is 0 unless n
    is not greater than or equal to 1.
```

A minimal example that illustrates my problem (`ex1.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%d\n" {1..3} | while read i; do
  printf "%d\n" {1..3} | while read j; do
    sum=$(expr $i + $j)
    echo "$i + $j = $sum"
    [ $sum -ge 5 ] && echo continue && continue 2
  done
  echo 'should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)'
done
```

Output of `ex1.sh`:

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 3 = 5
continue
should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)
3 + 1 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
continue
3 + 3 = 6
continue
should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)
```

Why is the `continue 2` ignored? It clearly echos out "continue", and the fact that continue runs is confirmed by running a trace with `set -x`

The use of `printf` is obviously silly `ex1.sh`, but reproduces the issue I'm having with getting continue to work in a `while read x...` loop.

A for loop works as expected (`ex2.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do
  for j in {1..3}; do
    sum=$(expr $i + $j)
    echo "$i + $j = $sum"
    [ $sum -ge 5 ] && echo continue && continue 2
  done
  echo 'should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)'
done
```

Output of `ex2.sh`:

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 3 = 5
continue
3 + 1 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
continue
```

So, why does `ex1.sh` seem to ignore the `continue 2` builtin, whereas `ex2.sh` behaves as expected?

Fixed the first example myself thanks to M. Nejat Aydin:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i; do
  while read j; do
    sum=$(expr $i + $j)
    echo "$i + $j = $sum"
    [ $sum -ge 5 ] && echo continue && continue 2
  done < <(printf "%d\n" {1..3})
  echo 'should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)'
done < <(printf "%d\n" {1..3})
```

The issue is that pipelines create subshells, so my continue statement was behaving as expected according to the manual, continuing at the outermost loop that subshell was aware of.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you. Totally forgot that pipes create a subshell. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've done it and added a corrected version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loops are not nested. They're running in different subshells. `continue` cannot continue from the parent shell. A pipe (`|`) creates a subshell. On the other hand, the version below should work as expected because both `while`s are running in the same shell:

```
while read i; do
  while read j; do
    sum=$(expr $i + $j)
    echo "$i + $j = $sum"
    [ $sum -ge 5 ] && echo continue && continue 2
  done < <(printf "%d\n" {1..3})
  echo 'should only see this for first cycle of i (2+3 >= 5)'
done < <(printf "%d\n" {1..3})
```